# How to use regular expression to search specific package in software source? [Ubuntu]

Tags: regex, ubuntu

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I know traditional approach is using `sudo apt-cache search`, but this command isn't best method. For example, if i want to search numpy, it will show many irrelevant packages just like following. I need to search one by one, is there better method?

```
.....
python3-tables-dbg - hierarchical database for Python 3 based on HDF5 (debug extension)
python3-tables-lib - hierarchical database for Python3 based on HDF5 (extension)
reinteract - Worksheet-based graphical Python shell
stimfit - Program for viewing and analyzing electrophysiological data
stimfit-dbg - Debug symbols for stimfit
texlive-lang-italian - TeX Live: Italian
python-spyderlib-doc - python IDE for scientists (Documentation)
python3-spyderlib - python IDE for scientists (Python 3)
spyder-common - python IDE for scientists (common files)
......
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`apt-cache search` searches the package name and description for the given regex pattern, you can make the Regex pattern more robust and search only on the package names by `--names-only` option:

```
apt-cache search --names-only '^python3?-numpy'
```

Also you don't need `sudo` to run `apt-cache`.

- `^python3?-numpy` matches package names begin with `python3-numpy` or `python-numpy`
- If you want to search only on the `python3` packages, use `^python3-numpy`
- To just get the package names:

  ```
  apt-cache search --names-only '^python3?-numpy' | awk '{print $1}'
  ```

**Example:**

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only '^python3?-numpy'
python-numpy - Numerical Python adds a fast array facility to the Python language
python-numpy-dbg - Fast array facility to the Python language (debug extension)
python-numpy-doc - NumPy documentation
python3-numpy - Fast array facility to the Python 3 language
python3-numpy-dbg - Fast array facility to the Python 3 language (debug extension)
python-numpydoc - Sphinx extension to support docstrings in Numpy format

$ apt-cache search --names-only '^python3?-numpy' | awk '{print $1}'
python-numpy
python-numpy-dbg
python-numpy-doc
python3-numpy
python3-numpy-dbg
python-numpydoc
```

Comment: In some cases, I don't know the exact package name is `python-numpy`, i just know `numpy`, how should i do?

Comment: If you only know part you can simply search `numpy` and it will return all packages that have that in the name or description. Or as above you can replace the `python3?` with a `*` and that will search for any packages ending with `numpy`. Though you are better off just doing the `numpy` only search in that case.

Comment: `apt search --names-only` also works.